# input field properties selectionStart / selectionEnd updated with delay

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener, event-listener

Two EventListener (`click` and `select`) log input fields properties `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`.

**Select a range** *(with double click or mouse selection)* inside the input field, the EventListener for `select` gets fired, `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are **logged as expected** (`selectionStart < selectionEnd`).

**Then click** inside the input field to clear the selection and show the caret. The EventListener for `click` gets fired, `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are logged with the **same values again** (`selectionStart < selectionEnd`).

**Then click** inside the input field **again**. The EventListener for `click` gets fired again, `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` are logged with the **correct values** (`selectionStart === selectionEnd`).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    const selectionStart = e.target.selectionStart;
    const selectionEnd = e.target.selectionEnd;
    console.log(selectionStart, selectionEnd);

  })
})

document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('select', (e) => {

    const selectionStart = e.target.selectionStart;
    const selectionEnd = e.target.selectionEnd;
    console.log(selectionStart, selectionEnd);

  })
})
```

```html
<input value="foobar">
```

(or on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x912yfpt/1/)

My guess is, that it takes time to update the node, so that the first click reads the old values. This is confirmed by a test function that reads the selection in a short interval. This reads the correct values **after** the first and **before** the second click.